# How to display ClickOnce Version number on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce

I have a windows forms application that is deployed to two different locations.

- Intranet - ClickOnce
- Internet - Installed on a citrix farm through Windows installer

I display ClickOnce version number for click-once deployed version`ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed`.

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
```

But for the non-click application, I am not sure how to retrieve clickonce version unless I hardcode the version number in assembly info.

Is there an automatic way of retrieve ClickOnce version number for non-clickonce deployed version?

Comment: I have always wondered how Microsoft decided two versions for a program would be useful.. and then give no way to tie the two together. Oy...

Comment: It's quite beautiful really, as unintentional as it is. Cpg's answer has become so popular, because it answer's the questions people visiting this page after typing their own question into a search engine, whereas JaredPar's answer has been marked the best answer, yet still isn't very popular at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No I do not believe that there is a way.  I believe the ClickOnce information comes from the manifest which will only be available in a ClickOnce deployment.  I think that hard coding the version number is your best option.

Comment: @JaredPar: Thank you and I will actually try to leave the question open to see if anyone has encountered the similar situation and was able to come up with some work-arounds.

Comment: +1 Because cpg's answer is just reiterating the 'solution' from the question (albeit with some more details).

Answer (score 110):

1. **Add an assembly reference to `System.Deployment` to your project.**
2. **Import the namespace in your class file:**

   VB.NET:

   ```
   Imports System.Deployment.Application
   ```

   C#:

   ```
   using System.Deployment.Application;
   ```
3. **Retrieve the ClickOnce version from the `CurrentVersion` property.**

   You can obtain the current version from the `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion` property. This returns a [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) object.

   Note (from MSDN):

   > *`CurrentVersion` will differ from `UpdatedVersion` if a new update has
   >   been installed but you have not yet called `Restart`. If the deployment
   >   manifest is configured to perform automatic updates, you can compare
   >   these two values to determine if you should restart the application.*

   NOTE: The `CurrentDeployment` static property is only valid when the application has been deployed with ClickOnce. Therefore before you access this property, you should check the `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` property first. It will always return a false in the debug environment.

   VB.NET:

   ```
   Dim myVersion as Version

   If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
      myVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
   End If
   ```

   C#:

   ```
   Version myVersion;

   if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
      myVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
   ```
4. **Use the `Version` object:**

   From here on you can use the version information in a label, say on an "About" form, in this way:

   VB.NET:

   ```
   versionLabel.Text = String.Concat("ClickOnce published Version: v", myVersion)
   ```

   C#:

   ```
   versionLabel.Text = string.Concat("ClickOnce published Version: v", myVersion);
   ```

   (`Version` objects are formatted as a four-part number (major.minor.build.revision).)

Comment: How is this upvoted [currently] 106 times when it doesn't even answer the original question?
The original question already says it knows about `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion`, and this answer just says to use that. The asker very clearly wants to know how to get the version when running as a non-ClickOnce app. The only way I know how to do that is during development by manually parsing a relative path to the .csproj or using `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project'.

Comment: This doesn't work with .NET Core (.NET 5 and above) since there is no System.Deployment. Is there an update way to get the ClickOnce version that doesn't use System.Deployment?

Comment: @AMG I have added an answer for .net Core

Answer (score 8):

I would simply make the assembly version of the main assembly the same as the CLickOnce version every time you put out a new version. Then when it runs as a non-clickonce application, just use Reflection to pick up the assembly version.

Comment: why not use the version of the main assembly when run as clickonce as well?

Comment: You have to change the ClickOnce version, or it won't install as an update. I generally try to keep the assembly version and ClickOnce version the same, or at least in the same minor version, depending on what our release versions are going to be.

Comment: The problem with using the AssemblyInfo is that it won't automatically keep the assembly version the same as the ClickOnce version. This will be a manual change that all the developers in the team will have to make each time someone deploys.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution for .NET (Core) 7 and higher**

On .net Core, you can read the version number from the environment variable `ClickOnce_CurrentVersion`.

```
string versionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_CurrentVersion") ?? "0.0.0.0";
Version version= Version.Parse(versionString);
MessageBox.Show(version.ToString());
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-deployment-properties-dotnet)

Comment: I was able to use this code on a .NET Core 3.1 app as well

Answer (score 3):

not that it matters three years later, but I ended up just parsing the manifest file with xml reader.

Comment: Why not use cpg's solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try thread verification:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion != ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdatedVersion)
    {
        Application.ExitThread();
        Application.Restart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on RobinDotNet's solution:

Protip: You can automatically run a program or script to do this for you from inside the .csproj file MSBuild configuration every time you build. I did this for one Web application that I am currently maintaining, executing a Cygwin bash shell script to do some version control h4x to calculate a version number from Git history, then pre-process the assembly information source file compiled into the build output.

A similar thing could be done to parse the ClickOnce version number out of the project file i.e., `Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationRevision` and `Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationVersion` (albeit I don't know what the version string means, but you can just guess until it breaks and fix it then) and insert that version information into the assembly information.

**I don't know when the ClickOnce version is bumped, but probably after the build process so you may need to tinker with this solution to get the new number compiled in.** *I guess there's always `/*h4x*/ +1`*.

I used Cygwin because *nix scripting is so much better than Windows and interpreted code saves you the trouble of *building your pre-build program before building*, but you could write the program using whatever technology you wanted (including C#/.NET). The command line for the pre-processor goes inside the `PreBuildEvent`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>
    $(CYGWIN_ROOT)bin\bash.exe --login -c refresh-version
  </PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As you'd imagine, this happens before the build stage so you can effectively pre-process your source code just before compiling it. I didn't want to be automatically editing the `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file so to play it safe what I did was create a `Properties\VersionInfo.base.cs` file that contained a text template of a class with version information and was marked as `BuildAction=None` in the project settings so that it wasn't compiled with the project:

```
using System.Reflection;
using EngiCan.Common.Properties;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.$REVNUM_DIV(100)$.$REVNUM_MOD(100)$.$DIRTY$")]
[assembly: AssemblyRevisionIdentifier("$REVID$")]
```

(A very dirty, poor-man's placeholder syntax resembling Windows' environment variables with some additional h4x thrown in was used for simplicity's/complexity's sake)

`AssemblyRevisionIdentifierAttribute` was a custom attribute that I created to hold the Git SHA1 since it is much more meaningful to developers than *a.b.c.d*.

My `refresh-version` program would then copy that file to `Properties\VersionInfo.cs`, and then do the substitution of the version information that it already calculated/parsed (I used `sed(1)` for the substitution, which was another benefit to using Cygwin). `Properties\VersionInfo.cs` was compiled into the program. That file can start out empty and you should ignore it by your version control system because it is automatically changing and the information to generate it is already stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

### One possible method is to extract the information from the application's manifest file

```
string version = "N/A";
    
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
string manifestPath = assembly.Location + ".manifest";

XmlDocument manifestXml = new XmlDocument();
manifestXml.Load(manifestPath);

XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new 
XmlNamespaceManager(manifestXml.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("asmv1", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");

XmlNode 
versionNode = 
manifestXml.SelectSingleNode("//asmv1:assembly/asmv1:assemblyIdentity/@version", namespaceManager);

if (versionNode != null)
{
version = versionNode.Value;
}
```

Comment: it seems rather silly that this is the best solution so far. I had to resort to the same after giving up on all the suggestions found on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Hard code, or... Keep track on your versions (File, Assembly, Deploy) in a database. Make a call to the database with your Assembly and get the Deploy version.

This assumes that you are incrementing your versions in a logical way such that each version type has a relationship. It's a lot of work for such a minor problem. I'd personally go with Jared's solution; although I hate hard coding anything.

Comment: @Coov: " I hate hard coding anything" That is exactly why I was thinking about if there was a way to get around this.  I have not thought about database to keep track of version numbers.  Thank you for another way to solve this issue.

Comment: It makes little sense to me to store it in the database. It is similar to hard coding it. Why not utilize the manifest, which increments on each publish?

Answer (score 2):

Using a build component, you could read the click-once version from the project file and write it automatically to the assembly info so both of them are in sync.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?