# Display Excel Add In Version using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to display the current project version of an excel add in, on the Excel menu bar.

This is a snippet of my code, which is located in the

```
private void TPFCRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    loginGroup.Label = "v" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
}
```

Here is the project version:

[image: Project Version]

And the result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, it always displays the Version 1.0, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different version numbers at play here:

- Assembly version, and
- ClickOnce publish version

(Note: In a Visual Studio solution you can have multiple assemblies with each having their own assembly version, but there will only be a single publish version when your add-in is deployed.)

Currently, your add-in displays the assembly version. This version number is set in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file (in the Properties subfolder of your project) or you can set it via the projects properties pages under *Application -> Assembly Information*.

If you want to show the ClickOnce publish version, you will need to extract that info from the ClickOnce manifest. Luckily, @cpg already documented very well how to do this: **[How to display ClickOnce Version number on Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734642/40347)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this because your executing assembly will be Excel if I am not wrong

```
loginGroup.Label = "v" +    
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(<ClassName>)).GetName().Version.ToString();
```