# How can I get the full publish version of a .NET (not framework) ClickOnce assembly at runtime in C#

Tags: .net-core, clickonce

I can't seem to find a way to grab the ClickOnce publish version of a .NET (not Framework) WPF app. I can get the the publish version from the assembly but that's a hard coded value that gets set in the project's .csproj.

I need the auto-incremented publish version from the ClickOnce at runtime in C#.

In .NET Framework I could do the following:

```
            ApplicationDeployment AD = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
            PublishVersion = AD.CurrentVersion.ToString();
```

I can't find anything analagous in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't exist in .net core or .NET 5(though it might get [ported](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/27)), but this might offer what you need -> https://github.com/derskythe/WpfSettings

Comment: Whoa! OK. Not pretty (but pretty clever). Let me see if I can make that work. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75263211/5258906) it is as easy as

```
string versionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_CurrentVersion") ?? "0.0.0.0";
Version version= Version.Parse(versionString);
MessageBox.Show(version.ToString());
```

I haven't tried it, but came across this issue and read literally 5 seconds before the answer given by @NineBerry and thus thought to link it here.