# Accessing Published Version Number In .Net6 Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, publish

The past applications I've written were on .Net Framework, I've moved to .Net6 for my current project and some of the C# I had previously used on .Net Framework 4.x.x no longer works with the .Net6 WinForms app. I want to be able to pull the published version number of the application and have it as a string in code.

Previously on Framework I had used something like...

```
var ver = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
```

It looks like .Net6 doesnt have `System.Deplyment` which I'm assuming is because it is built off of Core.
I've searched around but all of the solutions either don't pull the *Published* version, or are solutions that work on Framework and not on .Net6.

The current Published Version # is **0.0.1**, This is set in the ClickOnce pusblish dialog. This is the number I need to access.
I have tried the following...

```
string ver = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion;
```

Returns: `1.0.0`

```
string ver = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

Returns: `1.0.0.0`

```
string ver = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Returns: `1.0.0.0`

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Returns: `1.0.0.0`

None of those seem to be pulling the version Number I'm looking for, I assume those are set somewhere else in the properties.
Is there a way for me to access the Published application version number from inside Form.cs in a basic Windows Form app built on .Net6?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-deployment-properties-dotnet?view=vs-2022

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75263211/101087